# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'H:/_netrc'

Tags: heroku

Im trying to load a code I wrote onto Heroku but when i tried to do:
`heroku git:remote -a [the name of the app on Heroku]`
it said this:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'H:/_netrc'`

edit:
I tried to do:
`Heroku login`
And it did the same error.

edit:
I saw someone suggesting to do

1. cmd>set HomeDrive=c:/users/xxx
2. run the heroku login
3. when finished it will create _netrc in directory c:/users/xxx
   But it didn't work for me.

on a side note, from what I read I suppose the _netrc file suppose to save your login information to Heroku? (Heroku username and password)  on top of that , Heroku states that using the command : `heroku login`
will create the _netrc file if not existed yet, but for some reason Heroku doesnt create the file but perhaps only trying to update a missing file which causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out after talking to their support that the thing that worked for me is:

```
set HomeDrive=C:/Users/your Windows username/AppData/Local/heroku
```

(change the windows username with ur path)
and then just do:

```
heroku login
```

it will fix it
(altho u will have to do that every time u want to use heroku because the problem will keep repeating after you close the cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue...turns out there's a typo in the instructions, it should be:

set HomeDrive=c:\users\xxx

Changed the slash directions and it worked for me!

Comment: it now says to me instead of the original error message this: 
```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:/users/xxx/_netrc'```
is there a chance I perhaps wrote it wrong?
I tried first to do only: set HomeDrive=c:\users\xxx
then heroku login
but it didnt work.
so I tried : cmd>set HomeDrive=c:\users\xxx
instead which also didnt work